# Display content on same page based on drop down Selection

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, loops

This code does not currently work. I am using wordpress and trying to display content according to the drop down selected. To be more specific, the content is a different loop based on the taxonomy.

```
<form method="post" action="">
<select name="only_criteria" onchange="submit();">
        <option selected="selected">Please Choose</option>
        <option value="one">One</option>
        <option value="two">Two</option>
        <option value="three">Three</option>
</select>
</form>

<div class="archive-wrap">
 <div class="carousel">
<?php 
 if(isset($_POST['only_criteria']) && $_POST['only_criteria'] == '')  {   
$loop = new WP_Query( array( 
    'post_type' => 'my_custom_post_type',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'my_taxonomy',
                'terms'    => array( 'tax_one','tax_two','tax_three'),
      ),
    ),
  ) );
  } else if(isset($_POST['only_criteria']) && $_POST['only_criteria'] == 'one')  {   
$loop = new WP_Query( array( 
    'post_type' => 'my_custom_post_type',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'my_taxonomy',
                'terms'    => array( 'tax_one'),
      ),
    ),
  ) );
  } else if(isset($_POST['only_criteria']) && $_POST['only_criteria'] == 'two')  {   
$loop = new WP_Query( array( 
    'post_type' => 'my_custom_post_type',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'my_taxonomy',
                'terms'    => array( 'tax_two'),
      ),
    ),
  ) );
  } else if(isset($_POST['only_criteria']) && $_POST['only_criteria'] == 'three')  {   
$loop = new WP_Query( array( 
    'post_type' => 'my_custom_post_type',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'my_taxonomy',
                'terms'    => array('tax_three'),
      ),
    ),
  ) );
  }
?>
```

I have done similar things with tabs by putting each loop in a tab. I was hoping to use the form because I think it would reduce load times and be more efficient.

Comment: Are you saying that your code works perfectly but  you need suggestion on your approach?

Comment: No, the above code does not work and I would like to make it work for the reasons I mentioned.

Comment: It could be better if you display from AJAX on selection change.